# How to open Powershell

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, copy

I want to start this powershell command with VBA(Excel):
(It´s working in a *.bat file.)

`copy /b "C:\Users\chris\Desktop\Downloader\2\2.107.ts" + "C:\Users\chris\Desktop\Downloader\2\2.108.ts" ""C:\Users\chris\Desktop\Downloader\2\0001.ts""`

My Vba code:

```
Dim strCommand
Dim Wsshell    
strCommand = "Powershell.exe -NoExit copy \b ""C:\Users\chris\Downloads\1.ts"" + ""C:\Users\chris\Downloads\2.ts"" + ""C:\Users\chris\Downloads\3.ts"" -Destination ""C:\Users\chris\Downloads\yeah.ts"""
Set Wsshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Wsshell.Run (strCommand)
```

Error in Powershell:

```
Copy-Item : Es wurde kein Positionsparameter gefunden, der das Argument "+" akzeptiert.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ copy \b C:\Users\chris\Downloads\1.ts + C:\Users\chris\Downloads\2.ts ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Comment: Why powershell, why not just cmd /c

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an open powershell issue really.

The issue you are facing is that cmd copy is not the same as powershell copy.
In powershell Copy is an alias for copy item and powershell doesn't use "+" the same way cmd does, it would actually use comas for a multiple file copy

See [Copy-item Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7)

More importantly your actual issue is not copying but it seems you are using /b with one destination so you are performing a binary merge.

To do so in powershell I suggest

```
get-content "C:\Users\chris\Downloads\1.ts", "C:\Users\chris\Downloads\2.ts", "C:\Users\chris\Downloads\3.ts" -Encoding Byte -Read 512 | Set-Content "C:\Users\chris\Downloads\yeah.ts" -Encoding Byte
```

Just make sure to escape the "Quotes" when calling from VB